# Is there a way to save to specific filenames in Squib?

Tags: ruby, squib

As a note, I am a relatively experienced Python programmer, but have only recently picked up ruby.

I am using the gem `squib` to generate cards for a card game.

Whilst the majority of this has been painless, I have hit an issue when trying generate specific filenames from data inside the source CSV when saving to PNG.

The standard code to generate PNGs within squib is as follows:

```
save_png dir: "testdecks/build_#{buildstring}"
```

This works perfectly, and generates a series of cards in `./testdecks/build_ddmmyyhhmm` in the format `card_00.png`

The source file contains columns for Filename and Quantity, but with the following code I receive an error:

```
save_png dir: "testdecks/build_#{buildstring}", prefix: data['Filename'] + '[' + data['Quantity'] + ']'
```

error:

```
C:/Users/Francis/RubymineProjects/thewalls/thewalls_builder.rb:35:in `block in <top (required)>': no implicit conversion of String into Array (TypeError)
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/squib-6149023dbbac/lib/squib/deck.rb:74:in `instance_eval'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bundler/gems/squib-6149023dbbac/lib/squib/deck.rb:74:in `initialize'
    from C:/Users/Francis/RubymineProjects/thewalls/thewalls_builder.rb:17:in `new'
    from C:/Users/Francis/RubymineProjects/thewalls/thewalls_builder.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I believe the TypeError is from my trying to cat a string with an array, however I am not sure if there is a way to join two Squib::DataFrame arrays and add in extra characters.

As a workaround, I can bake it all into the filename field (e.g. `wall[8]` instead of `wall`) but that doesn't feel like the nice way to do it.

Is there any way to do this?
Also is there a way to make prefix the entire filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prefix` and `count_format` options do support arrays, so each card would be given a different prefix and/or count format.

By the way, you can use `count_format` as effectively a "suffix" or "the whole filename" if you need to - you can see how I concatenate them together here: https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/blob/master/lib/squib/args/save_batch.rb#L53-L55. Admittedly, we could handle this more intuitively (see https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/issues/159)

I believe the issue is coming in with how you're constructing the array of `prefix`s - I'm not sure `+` is doing what you think it does. Use something like `zip` and `map` to combine arrays. Like I did here: https://github.com/andymeneely/project-bolt-rats/blob/master/lib/deck.rb#L41-L44

```
  png_prefixes = data.card.zip(data.size).map do |c,s|
    "creature_#{s}_#{c}_".downcase
  end
  save_png prefix: png_prefixes
```

Comment: Thank you, those examples help a great deal, I'll have to rework and experiment.

With the count_format option, is `%02d` required as part of it? I have no direct use for the card numbers myself so it would be nice to be rid of them, though I am not sure whether this would affect something under the hood.

Comment: Nope - `%02d` is not required. If you don't have it, you'll just have no numbers I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I find map is an effective tool for generating arbitrary arrays to feed squib.  Load everything from a csv, map some columns with complex transformations, create a deck.

I also use enumerate if I'm combining inputs from multiple columns in csv so I can index the others.